# What are the names of the keys for mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

Where can I find, e.g., what `<CR>` and `<c` (in `<c-o>`) mean?
Like, OK, I can encounter them with the meaning along, but I just want to look up it in some list of all the keys.
So, is there a list with the meanings of these denotations and a brief explanation of the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are "keycode" notation. See `:h keycodes`.

You can get the help of a command using `:h CTRL-O` for `<c-o>`. Or you can use `:h <c-v><c-o>` (where you actually press those keys).